# How to uppercase all first-letter-characters of sentences after specified delimiter in a text file?

Tags: c++, string, toupper

Just as the title says, I have text file that has virtually no uppercase letters in it, so all of the sentences don't look proper without the first letter capitalized. Here's my code so far:

```
    //This program reads an article in a text file, and changes all of the
//first-letter-of-sentence-characters to uppercase after a period and space.
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>//for toupper
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //Variable needed to read file:
    string str;
    string input = str.find('.');


    //Open the file:
    fstream dataFile("eBook.txt", ios::in);
    if (!dataFile)
    {
        cout << "Error opening file.\n";
        return 0;
    }
    //Read lines terminated by '. ' sign, and then output:
    getline(dataFile, input, '. ');//error: no instance of overloaded function "getline"
                                   //matches the argument list
                                   //argument types are:(std::fstream, std::string, int)
    while (!dataFile.fail())
    {
        cout << input << endl;
        getline(dataFile, input);
    }
    //Close the file:
    dataFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

.
NOTE: I know there is no toupper keyword in my code yet. I don't know where to set it yet.

Comment: Why are you searching an empty string: `input = str.find('.');` ?

Comment: Try this:  `while (getline(datafile, input, '.'))`  You can't put more than one character between single quotes, use double quotes.

Comment: So a period and a blank space is considered two characters?

Comment: Yes, a period is a character.  A space is a character.  Together, they are two characters.

Comment: Things become even more complicated if you take non ASCII-characters into account. A fully fledged Unicode solution would need a good Unicode library.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

```
    getline(dataFile, input, '. ');
    while (!dataFile.fail())
    {
        cout << input << endl;
        getline(dataFile, input);
    }
```

You can change it to

```
    while(getline(dataFile, line, '.'))
    {
        for(auto &i : line )
        {
            if(!isspace(i))
            {
                i = toupper(i);
                break;
            }  
        }
        outFile<<line<<".";
    }
```

PS: I would prefer using RegEx for this kind of problems.